# How can I read/write a fixed number of ints from/to file in one operation (as fast as I can, file can be assumed to be binary)?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I have a big file (let's assume I can make it binary), that can not fit in RAM, and I want to sort numbers from it. In the process I need to read/write a big amount of numbers from/to the file (from/to `vector<int>` or `int[]`) quickly, so I'd like not to read/write it one by one, but read/write it by blocks with a fixed size. How can I do it?

Comment: If it's a text file and not binary, you have no choice but to do it one number at a time because each one will require conversion.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok so let's assume it is binary.

Comment: Have you looked at [`istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)?

Comment: @RSahu I can't actually understand how to work with them. They read/write bytes, right? How can I understand, how many bytes do I need to read/write? How do I convert bytes to integers for working with them?

Comment: Even faster, use OS-specific calls such as POSIX `open()` and `write()` on Linux.  If you need to run as fast as you can, you can't ignore the underlying implementation.

Comment: The number of bytes per `int` is `sizeof(int)`, almost by definition.

Comment: Merge Sort.  Initially created to sort files of numbers when the quantity of numbers could not fit into the computer's memory.

Comment: Your performance bottleneck is the file I/O.  Modern hard drives (and SSD) have serial data channels; everything gets squeezed into one channel.  The data then has to be placed into the PC's memory.  The time consuming operations are locating the sector containing the data and waiting for the drive to come up to speed.  This overhead can be reduced by keeping the data flowing (streaming) and reading in large chunks of data to reduce the quantity of operations.  Algorithms may be able to reduce this slightly, but still file I/O is the performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a big file (let's assume I can make it binary), that can not fit in RAM, and I want to sort numbers from it.

Given that the file is binary, perhaps the simplest and presumably efficient solution is to memory map the file. Unfortunately there is no standard interface to perform memory mapping. On POSIX systems, there is the `mmap` function.

Now, the memory mapped file is simply an array of raw bytes. Treating it as an array of integers is technically not allowed until C++20 where C-style "implicit creation of low level objects" is introduced. In practice, that already works on most current language implementations <sup>Note 1</sup>.

For this reinterpretation to work, the representation of the integers in the file must match the representation of integers used by the CPU. The file will not be portable to the same program running on other, incompatible systems.

We can simply use `std::sort` on this array. The operating system should take care of paging the file in and out of memory. The algorithm used by `std::sort` isn't necessarily optimised for this use case however. To find the optimal algorithm, you may need to do some research.

<sup>1</sup> In case Pre-C++20 standard conformance is a concern, it is possible to iterate over the array, copy the underlying bytes into an integer, placement-new an integer object into the memory using the copied integer as the new value. A compiler can optimise these operations into zero instructions, and this makes the program's behaviour well defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to write into a file and [`istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read from a file.

To make the process clean, it will be good to have the number of items also in the file.

Let's say you have a `vector<int>`.

You can use the following code to write its contents to a file.

```
std::vector<int> myData;
// .. Fill up myData;

// Open a file to write to, in binary mode.
std::ofstream out("myData.bin", std::ofstream::binary);

// Write the size first.
auto size = myData.size();
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&size), sizeof(size));

// Write the data.
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(myData.data()), sizeof(int)*size);
```

You can read the contents of such a file using the following code.

```
std::vector<int> myData;

// Open the file to read from, in binary mode.
std::ifstream in("myData.bin", std::ifstream::binary);

// Read the size first.
auto size = myData.size();
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));

// Resize myData so it has enough space to read into.
myData.resize(size);

// Read the data.
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(myData.data()), sizeof(int)*size);
```

---

If not all of the data can fit into RAM, you can read and write the data in smaller chunks. However, if you read/write them in smaller chunks, I don't know how you would sort them.

Comment: How do you sort the file in chunks?

Comment: @eerorika, I don't have an answer to that.

Comment: Merge Sort.  By definition, sorts one or more files using chunks.